# Logic in PySpark Dataframe to include the previous row value using the lag function

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to apply a logic in calculating the balance for a date. Where the current generated row is dependent on previous row value, For a null condition.

Below is representation of problem statement in tabular format. First Four columns are available in data frame.

| Date_Id | Grade_Id | Open_Balance | Actuals | Base |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230301 | 6 | 1000 | 100 | 80 |
| 20230302 | 6 | 900 | 100 | 50 |
| 20230303 | 6 | null | null | 20 |
| 20230304 | 6 | null | null | 10 |
| 20230301 | 3 | 500 | 50 | 30 |
| 20230302 | 3 | 450 | 30 | 20 |
| 20230303 | 3 | null | null | 20 |
| 20230304 | 3 | null | null | 20 |

Expected output:

| Date_Id | Grade_Id | Open_Balance | Actuals | Base | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230301 | 6 | 1000 | 100 | 80 | 900 |
| 20230302 | 6 | 900 | 200 | 50 | 1600 |
| 20230303 | 6 | null | null | 30 | 1570 |
| 20230304 | 6 | null | null | 20 | 1550 |
| 20230301 | 3 | 500 | 50 | 30 | 450 |
| 20230302 | 3 | 450 | 30 | 20 | 970 |
| 20230303 | 3 | null | null | 20 | 950 |
| 20230304 | 3 | null | null | 20 | 930 |

Since the open_Balance for 20230303 is NULL, 'Output' attribute should be considering the 'Base' value of 20230303 and subtract with the previous balance i.e.(20230302 : (700-30))
And similarly it continues

Code I'm  using to achieve the above scenario

```
w =  Window.partitionBy("Grade_Id").orderBy("Date_Id")
Test_Query_DF = Test_Query_DF.withColumn("C", col("Open_Balance"))
#Test_Query_DF.display()

df2 = (
      Test_Query_DF
     .withColumn("D", F.col("C") - F.col("Actuals"))
     .withColumn("D", when(col("C").isNull(),
                          F.lag("D").over(w))
                    .otherwise(F.col("C") - F.col("Actuals")))
)
df2.display()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the cumulative sum of the existance of the column value, you can split the data with the temp partition and set all the values same as in the partition that will fill the null values.

**Edited**

With the `Base` column requirement, use `coalesce` and `sum`.

```
w1 = Window.orderBy('Date_Id')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('temp').orderBy('Date_Id')

df.withColumn('temp', f.col('Open_Balance').isNotNull().cast('int')) \
  .withColumn('temp', f.sum('temp').over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('D', f.first(f.col('Open_Balance')).over(w2) - f.sum(f.coalesce('Actuals', 'Base')).over(w2)) \
  .drop('temp') \
  .show()

+--------+--------+------------+-------+----+---+
| Date_Id|Grade_Id|Open_Balance|Actuals|Base|  D|
+--------+--------+------------+-------+----+---+
|20230301|       6|        1000|    100|  80|900|
|20230302|       6|         900|    200|  50|700|
|20230303|       6|        null|   null|  30|670|
|20230304|       6|        null|   null|  20|650|
+--------+--------+------------+-------+----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However tried implementing the same in my code which had few additional attributes and failed. Have edited the Question with actual Dataframe input and Expected output. Can you please let me know the approach to achieve the same. Have included the 'Base' and 'output' attributes

Comment: Sorry had missed one requirement where i have to sum the previous left balance with new Balance. Have update the table structure can you please help me out here also have created a new one for the same. please advise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75721426/logic-in-pyspark-dataframe-to-sum-the-previous-row-value-with-the-current-row/75725080#75725080