# Logic in PySpark Dataframe to sum the previous row value with the current row

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to apply a logic in calculating the balance for a date. Where the current generated row is dependent on previous row value.

Below is representation of problem statement in tabular format

| Date | Id | Balance | Spent | Base |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | 3 | 1000 | 100 | 10 |
| 20230102 | 3 | null | 50 | 10 |
| 20230103 | 3 | null | null | 10 |
| 20230104 | 3 | 500 | null | 10 |

Expected Output:

| Date | Id | Balance | Spent | Base | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | 3 | 1000 | 50 | 10 | 900 |
| 20230102 | 3 | null | 50 | 10 | 850 |
| 20230103 | 3 | null | null | 10 | 840 |
| 20230104 | 3 | 500 | null | 10 | 1330 |

Below is the code i'm trying to achieve the same

```
w1 =  Window.partitionBy("Id").orderBy("Date")
w2 = Window.partitionBy('temp','Id').orderBy('Date')

df.withColumn('temp', f.col('Balance').isNotNull().cast('int'))
  .withColumn('temp', f.sum('temp').over(w1))
  .withColumn('D', f.first(f.col('Balance')).over(w2) - f.sum(f.coalesce('Spent','Base')).over(w2)).show()
```

For the Date 20230104 previous balance "800" should be sum'd up with new balance 500 and then used for calculation i.e. 800+500 - 50 = 1250
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all `Balance` up till current row and minus the all `Spent` up till current row.

```
w = (Window.partitionBy('Id')
           .orderBy('Date')
           .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))

df = df.withColumn('Output', f.sum('Balance').over(w) - f.sum('Spent').over(w))
```

Result

```
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
|    Date| Id|Balance|Spent|Base|Output|
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
|20230101|  3|   1000|  100|  10|   900|
|20230102|  3|   null|   50|  10|   850|
|20230103|  3|   null|   50|  10|   800|
|20230104|  3|    500|   50|  10|  1250|
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
```

=============================================

**Update**

To add `Base` in equation.

```
w = (Window.partitionBy('Id')
           .orderBy('Date')
           .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow))

df = (df.withColumn('Output', f.sum('Balance').over(w) - f.sum('Spent').over(w)
                              - f.sum(f.when(f.col('Spent').isNull(), f.col('Base')).otherwise(f.lit(0))).over(w)))
```

Result

```
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
|    Date| Id|Balance|Spent|Base|Output|
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
|20230101|  3|   1000|  100|  10|   900|
|20230102|  3|   null|   50|  10|   850|
|20230103|  3|   null| null|  10|   840|
|20230104|  3|    500| null|  10|  1330|
+--------+---+-------+-----+----+------+
```

Comment: That's not expected as its the New Balance that gets added up on the next day. So it should be a sum of previous  'Output' column with new 'Balance'

Comment: It ends up in a same equation. `Output1 = Balance1 - Spent1; Output2 = Output1 + Balance2 - Spent2 = (Balance1 - Spent1) + Balance2 - Spent2 = (Balance1 + Balance2) - (Spent1 + Spent2)`

and result is same.  In Spark, you don't want to depend on the last result. it is better to convert it to only depend on the data that already exists on dataframe.

Comment: There is a challenge in applying this logic, I have modifed the input tables and output tables. If could check that, If the Spent value is null then 'Base' value should be considered to calculate the output from the previous balance

Comment: I updated my answer.  Could you also update your description of `800+500 - 50 = 1250` in question?